# Convert date to gmt - php

Tags: php

I am having a strange problem, maybe you can help:

I'm trying to convert a date to GMT time, and this is what I'm doing:

```
$date = '2010-05-27 23:02:01';
$gmt_date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date );
```

but the yield of `$gmt_date` is this:
`1970-01-01 00:33:31`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`gmdate` expects the second parameter to be an integer (the number of seconds from the unix epoch)

Try this:

```
$date = '2010-05-27 23:02:01'; 
$gmt_date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date) );
```

Comment: You have to set the timezone first or this will return the same date and time.
`date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');`

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert your $date into a timestamp.  You can do this using the strtotime() function.  Depending on timezones, you may want to set the php timezone or append a timezone to the $date string before calling the strtotime function.

```
$gmdate_str = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```