# Php Convert time in gmt format

Tags: php, time, gmt

I have this string `2012-06-27 16:17:06` and I want to convert it to GMT format.
How can I do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert date to gmt - php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796015/convert-date-to-gmt-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's DateTime Object is a good choice:

```
$GMT = new DateTimeZone("GMT");
$date = new DateTime( "2011-01-01 15:00:00", $GMT );
$date->setTimezone( $newTZ );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [gmdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php).
Convert your current date format to UNIX timestamp by using `strtotime` and then use `gmdate($format, $timestamp);`

Comment: $time=strtotime("2012-06-27 16:17:06");
 gmdate($format, $time);
but what value i have to assign at $format?

Answer (score 2):

Well, strictly speaking you can not do it.
If you do not know in what TZ that date has been generated you can not convert it to another TZ.

If that date came from a DB, probably you can query a date with the original TZ.

```
$date = new DateTime( "2011-01-01 15:00:00", $original_TZ ); 
$date->setTimezone( "GMT" );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Set timeline
$time_line = time() +7200; // <-- this is timeline +2
$h = gmdate('h', $time_line);
$i = gmdate('i', $time_line);
$s = gmdate('s', $time_line);

$time = $h.":".$i.":".$s;

echo $time;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It will work

```
$newTZ = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");  
$GMT = new DateTimeZone("GMT");
$date = new DateTime( "2018-09-20 6:00:00 PM", $newTZ );
$date->setTimezone($GMT);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$time = '2012-06-27 16:17:06';
echo date("l, F j, Y, g:i a",strtotime($time) ); // assuming gmt format
```

taken from [How do I get Greenwich Mean Time in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851574/how-do-i-get-the-gmt-time-in-php)