# How to convert different time zone date & time to GMT time in php

Tags: php, date

I have following date formats

```
$date_format1 = "Sat, 31 May 2014 00:00:00 +0200";
$date_format2 = "Mon, 02 Jun 2014 14:00:00 -0400";
$date_format3 = "Mon, 02 Jun 2014 11:03:00 BST";
$date_format4 = "Mon, 02 Jun 2014 10:03:00 EDT";
```

What will be the PHP code to convert all above formats at GMT.
Note: I required only single(If possible) function to handle all above format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gmdate()` function will output the date/time in GMT and the `strtotime()` function will convert your datetime strings to a valid parameter for `gmdate()`.

```
$date_format1 = "Sat, 31 May 2014 00:00:00 +0200";
$date_format2 = "Mon, 02 Jun 2014 14:00:00 -0400";
$date_format3 = "Mon, 02 Jun 2014 11:03:00 BST";
$date_format4 = "Mon, 02 Jun 2014 10:03:00 EDT";


$newFormat = 'd/m/Y H:i:s';


echo gmdate($newFormat, strtotime($date_format1)) . PHP_EOL;
echo gmdate($newFormat, strtotime($date_format2)) . PHP_EOL;
echo gmdate($newFormat, strtotime($date_format3)) . PHP_EOL;
echo gmdate($newFormat, strtotime($date_format4)) . PHP_EOL;
```

And the results would be:-

```
30/05/2014 22:00:00
02/06/2014 18:00:00
02/06/2014 10:03:00
02/06/2014 14:03:00
```

Answer (score 0):

This exactly gives GMT time:

```
gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime ('+1 hour'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read about php function [gmdate()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)

Comment: Just linking to the help dosn't help much. Stack overfloww is about providing answers who can help the OP understand and provide information for other visitors

Comment: may be this will help you [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796015/convert-date-to-gmt-php)

Comment: Ztripez Hellström, this site also isn't place for free homework solutions. I'm trying to teach people to RTFM instead of posting numerious search&get questions.

Comment: If your not here to provide answers next time don't answer the question and down vote it with a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function `strtotime (string $time)` can be used to convert the text part of, say, `$date_format1` to a timestamp that can be used in the `gmstrftime()` function, so:

```
gmdate("<insert_date_format_here>", strtotime($date_format1));
```

See [Date Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php) and [Time Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php) from the PHP documentation.

Answer (score 0):

i create for u this function, it's easy hope it will help you

```
function datetoutc($d , $zone="UTC"){
    $d = new DateTime($d);
    $d->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($zone));
    return $d->getTimestamp();
}

print datetoutc("Sat, 31 May 2014 23:00:00 +0200");
```